# Is it correct to use と directly after こと when listing?

Tags: particles

It just comes across as odd to me to say 'koto to'. 
Is it grammatically correct to use と after こと as seen in the example below?

おんがく と かくこと と ねこ が 好き です！

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is correct. This こと is used for nominalization.

For example, 歩くことと読書が好きです (I like walking and reading).