# How do I connect verbs with nominalisation?

Tags: て-form, nominalization, particle-こと

For example:

> I like dancing and singing.
> My hobby is studying Japanese and playing guitar.

How do I connect "studying and playing"?
Do I have to use te form? I'm really confused

upd. nvm, you just connect it with と particle like 歌うことと踊るが好き

Comment: You know how to connect nouns, right? You use the word nominalisation in your question title. Have you thought about what that actually means?

Comment: You're update is almost correct. You forgot to nominalise 踊る. See also these links: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45259/is-it-correct-to-use-%e3%81%a8-directly-after-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-when-listing/45261#45261  and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62634/nominalizing-particle-combos

Comment: It's also worth noting that と is an exhaustive 'and' so you are saying that these are the **only** things you like doing. See this link for example: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48011/difference-between-a%e3%81%a8b-and-a%e3%82%84b Consider also the たり～たりする construct.